# Perl's hash of hash of hash redeclaration?

Tags: perl, hash

Lets suppose I have a Hash of Hash of Hash (%hash) with some values

```
warn Dumper \%hash;
     'Key1'=> {'Subkey1'} => {'SubSubkey11'} => {'Value1'} 
     'Key2'=> {'Subkey2'} => {'SubSubkey22'} => {'Value2'}
     ...
```

Then, want to verify if a certain combination of keys is absent (Assume there is a for above the if that loop over a series of combinations for $val1 and $val2 ).

```
if (!exists $hash{$val1}{$val2} ) {  #### I am only verifying the existent of the Key and Subkey, not SubSubkey
     print "Doesn't exists";
}
```

If I use after loop finish, I am going to see something like this:

```
warn Dumper\%hash; 
     'Key1' => {'Subkey1'} => {}
     'Key2' => {'Subkey2'} => {}
```

'Key1' and 'Subkey1' are somehow been "assigned" to void values and, because I may loop several times over the same combination of un-existent keys, after the first loop over a pair of keys the second if takes the combination as existent.

What causes this and which is the best way to solve it. I tried Dereferencing the hash inside the if and got this error

```
    exists argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or a subroutine
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are treating `$hash{$var1}` as a hash reference so it automatically becomes one; this is called autovivification and can be very handy.

You can disable it by installing and using the autovivification pragma:

```
if ( do { no autovivification; ! exists $hash{$var1}{$var2} } ) {
```

or you can manually do basically the same thing as that would do:

```
if ( ! exists ${ $hash{$var1} || {} }{$var2} ) {
```

(Here, if `$hash{$var1}` isn't set, we don't use it as a hash reference, we use an empty hash instead.)

Or, if it seems more readable to you, you can do:

```
if ( ! ( $hash{$var1} && exists $hash{$var1}{$var2} ) ) {
```

Comment: If the hash elements can never exist but have a *false* value (as you're assuming with `$hash{$var1} || {}`) then you can write just `unless ( $hash{$var1} and $hash{$var1}{$var2} ) { ... }`

Comment: at the cost of repeating `$hash{` and `$var1`, which may be complex expressions.  but, yes, in the simple case, that would be easier to read